# change angular jQLite with actual jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want angularjs to use jQuery instead of jQLite by default. Is it possible? So that in directive link function:

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
```

`element` must be jQuery object. Now i'm converting it manually and i don't like it:

```
 element = $(element[0]);
```

Comment: Why downvoting people, why :D

Comment: no need to wrap `element` in `$()` , it's already a jQUery object once jQ is loaded

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to add jquery script tag before angularjs, this way angularjs will automatically replace jqLite by jQuery.

```
<!-- Add jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Then, add angular -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: in the case I use jQuery because it is a dependency of a plugin I am using, will importing jQuery just for that plugin make jQuery the default for the whole application?

Comment: Yes, if jQuery is imported before angular.js, it will be be used for the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Mickael got the right answer.

Further, at the very end of the angular.js, there is...

```
  bindJQuery();
```

which will do the trick. It's not a magic.