# Different behaviour due to import order of AngularJS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write an AngularJS directive named "insert-after-parent" that inserts content after his parent. Inside this directive, I use jQuery to select the parent element. Because AngularJS is based on jQuery, I load first the jQuery and than the AngularJS framework. But when I do, my directive doesn't work. But if I first load AngularJS and then the jQuery framework, it works. Can someone tell my why?

```
angular.module('ls', []).directive('insertAfterParent', ["$compile", function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.src)
            }, function(id) {
                if(id){
                    var content = $('script[type="text/ng-template"][id="' + id + '"]').html()
                    if(content){
                        $compile($(content).insertAfter(element.parent()))(scope)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
  }])
```

Here the link to my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gTXk0bjyQ6nTTCaB9Czg?p=preview

I'm using angular 1.2.23 and jQuery 1.7.1
According to the documentation([AngularJS FAQ](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/misc/faq)), these versions are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Angular has a trimmed down version of jquery. Once you load angular - your full body jquery gets overwritten with the trimmed down version.

And please don't load jquery. You don't need it - unless you are somehow upgrading an old jquery solution to angularjs... When you find yourself needing jquery, it's the design of your app that is "wrong" or at last not done the angular way - declarative.

Comment: The jqLite version of AngularJS doesn't include all functions that I need for my directives. That's why I need to import jQuery.
In the FAQ is also sayed that you can use jQuery in AngularJS:
https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: I don't think you need those functions if you use angular correctly. When that is said, does my post not answer your question?

Comment: I've tried to do the directive completly in AnulgarJS. But I'm not able to do the insertAfter() because it's not supported by jqLite.

Comment: You could create a new question, asking how to solve it without jquery. Your question posted looks answered correctly though? Hint: Do not modify the dom with insertAfter, modify the data/scope variables and let angular draw the extra element instead

Comment: Your post doesn't answer my question. It is only a workaround. The code posted should work, see FAQ AngularJS.

Comment: It's not a workaround. You said yourself that loading angular first, then jquery work. That is the order you need to load them or angulars trimmed version overrides the other one...

Comment: "Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite."_picked from angular FAQ_
If I understand correctly, angular should detect that jquery was already loaded and not use the jqlite version.
See also: [change angular jQLite with actual jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855033/change-angular-jqlite-with-actual-jquery)

Comment: Ok, i reread the FAQ and i get what you are saying. The working load order is not optimal as angular will keep using the lite version, and you will use the full blown version. It does look like a bug to me though... Perhaps it's a bug in $compile and its use of $...