# Make html preview of blog post in Angular.js using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, blogs

I have a list of posts which loads perfect, the entire content of each post. The html post content  is a string in database column. Now I want to create a read more link at the position that I desire and only show a post preview in the list (a part of the html content). To accomplish that I write a comment inside the posts  it´s the point to cut the content in order to preview.

How can I manipulate the content before the `ng-bind-html` loads it? I need to detect the first  comment and clean the content html document. I´m making tests in `jquery` but i would like to know how to do it on the angular way.

I think that a filter inside the ng-bind-html expression can do the work. But i don´t now how to manipulate the html string inside the filter. Manipulate like jquery syntax because i need to remove a lot of tags and do some stuff.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var com = $("*")
           .contents()
           .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;})
           .first();
        com.nextAll().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function that will be executed during `ng-bind-html` and get access to your string by using sanitise service `$sce`. See the [details](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) on `$sanitise` service.

Inside the `ng-bind-html` you can manipulate the DOM using [jqlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) and native javascript (by using `$document` wrapper). If the manipulations are too complex, I'd use jquery directly. To do that you have to just [include it before angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855033/change-angular-jqlite-with-actual-jquery) in your index.html and use `angular.element` instead of `$`